# Flask session log out and redirect to login page

Tags: python, session, flask

I am using Flask,Python for my web application . The user will login and if the session time is more than 5 minutes then the app should come out and it should land on the login page.

I tried some of the methods and I can see the session time out is happening but redirect to login page is not happening.

```
@app.before_request
def before_request():
    "Session time out method"

    flask.session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = datetime.timedelta(minutes=2)
    flask.session.modified = True
    flask.g.user = flask_login.current_user
    #return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

I have used before_request for seesion time out.
I have referrred this link [Flask logout if sessions expires if no activity and redirect for login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39718259/flask-logout-if-sessions-expires-if-no-activity-and-redirect-for-login-page) 
but I dont see any changes from what I have tried before and this code. I can see lot of stackoverflow questions over there for this topic and I couldnt find the solution.

I have tried this link als
[Expire session in flask in ajax context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30354765/expire-session-in-flask-in-ajax-context)

But I am not sure what should I pass as a session and what qualifier I should return here?

```
@mod.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    if session_is_invalid(session):
        return redirect(url_for('logout'))

def session_is_invalid(ses):
    # return your qualifier
```

if the previous method is correct can some one tell me what is the session and what qualifier I should return here?

What I need is after session log out the page should automatically land on the login screen
What is happening is session log out is happening but it's not redirecting to login page

could some one help me in this?

Comment: Want to show a ui interface for unauthorized users?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. `flask_login` has the machinery to do this. Since you're using `@app.before_request` I assume that the redirect only has to happen after someone makes some action after the expiry time vs. just redirecting automatically redirecting after 5 minutes of idle time and not waiting for their next action?

Comment: @Fatih it's not like showing UI interface to unauthorized users. The user has logged in and didnt do any action for certain amount of time. After he comes back and if tries to perform some action it should do the session time out and redirect to login page. I need this work process. As of now session time out is happening and I get 401 unauthorized error.

Comment: @roganjoshYes I want the redirect should has to happen after someone makes some action after the expiry time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When I read the documents of the `Flask-Login` package, i saw a few things. When creating your `Flask` application, you also need to create a login manager.

```
login_manager = LoginManager()
```

A `login_view` variable in `LoginManager` class caught my attention. The details include the following explanation:

> The name of the view to redirect to when the user needs to log in. (This can be an absolute URL as well, if your authentication machinery is external to your application.)

Actually, after you create a `LoginManager` object,

```
login_manager.login_view = 'your login view'
```

You should specify your login page. Finally, 
Once the actual application object has been created, you can configure it for login with:

```
login_manager.init_app(app)
```

After doing these, any `unauthorized` calls to every method you use `@login_required` annotation will be sent to the page you have pointed out with `login_view`.

I also developed a simple application. You can review this application [from here](https://github.com/celikfatih/flask-login). I tested it and working without any problems.

I hope it helps you.